# How to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a time series spread?

Tags: time-series, mean, standard-deviation, cointegration

I am just starting anew in econometrics, and am presently trying out statistical arbitrage, specifically cointegration. I have stochastic time series data for variables A, B. Engle-Granger testing is used for the project. What I have done:

1. Performed a stationarity test.
2. Performed differencing
3. Performed OLS regression
4. Found the trading pair formula by calculating the spread. Which is spread = dependent (A) - regressor (B).

Now, where I got confused is how to get the mean and standard deviation of the spread. I'm a bit confused on how to calculate these, and I'll really appreciate it if I can get a help in this regard.

Please see the attached.csv file and simply enter your response when the file is opened in Excel.

[image: Scan QR code to see the csv file]

or go directly to it - https://fileport.io/gp9SsSBcaSwq

Comment: If you use Engle-Granger and find that A and B are cointegrated, why do you apply differencing?

Comment: Engel Granger dictates that the variables must be stationary at first difference.

Comment: It might be what a unit root test shows, but not what Engle-Granger dictates. Engle-Granger is about cointegration (a relationship between multiple integrated series), not about integration (a property of a single series). To find out about cointegration using the Engle-Granger procedure, you should not be differencing. Instead, you should run a regression of A on B as they are. If there is cointegration, the residual will be stationary. It will be the estimate of S.

Comment: @Richard Hardy, You're right. The differencing is done to check if the raw variables are stationary at first difference. Engel Granger test was done non the raw data. I have attached a CSV file to the main post. Could you add the formula  to calculate mean and standard deviation in Excel, and reshare with me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stationary combination $S$ of a pair of cointegrating time series $(A,B)$ can be treated as any stationary time series. If the cointegrating vector is $(1,-1)$, then $S:=A-B$ is stationary.

- Its (unconditional) **mean** can be estimated as the sample mean, just as you would do with i.i.d. data.
- The (unconditional) **standard deviation** can again be estimated as the sample standard deviation; see e.g. [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193713/estimating-unconditional-variance-in-time-series).
- The **standard error** of the mean can be estimated using autocorrelation-robust standard errors such as Newey-West.

Here is some R code:

```r
T=1e3
set.seed(1); x=arima.sim(model=list(ar1=0.9,ma1=-0.3),n=T)
mean=mean(x); print(mean)
sd  =sd  (x); print(sd  )
se  =sqrt(sandwich::NeweyWest(lm(x~1))); print(se)
```

Comment: I'm not using R for now, could you add the formula to calculate mean and standard deviation in Excel, and reshare with me? Thank you.

Comment: @ken4ward, Excel formulas are `=AVERAGE(...)` and `=STDEV.S(...)` where `...` is the range of the cells the time series occupies.